# Sword Collision detection with Enemy on Mouse Click

Tags: unity-game-engine

Video URL for easy understanding - `http://tinypic.com/r/28jdyyq/9`

In this video, you can see my problem, when the sword touches the enemy.. enemy gets destroyed.. But i want when i mouseclick (or hit), then only ..enemy should destroy..

```
void OnTriggerEnter(Collider col)
    {
        if (col.GetComponent<Collider>().tag == "enemy")
        {
            Destroy(col.gameObject);

        }
    }
```

This is my code, i have enemy and Player with sword (with collider) , everything is perfect, i want when i click mousebutton then only sword should kill enemy,

But, What is happening when i bring my player (with sword) near enemy and sword touches enemy, it is killing enemy without i hit by sword.

I tried the below code also by adding mouse click event inside Trigger , but nothing happens. Any idea Please

```
void OnTriggerEnter(Collider col)
    {

        if (Input.GetButtonDown("Fire1")){

                if (col.GetComponent<Collider>().tag == "enemy"){

                    Destroy(col.gameObject);
                }

        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try the same code in `OnTriggerStay` because `OnTriggerEnter` is only called once.

```
void OnTriggerStay(Collider col)
{
    if (Input.GetButtonDown("Fire1")){

        if (col.GetComponent<Collider>().tag == "enemy"){

            Destroy(col.gameObject);
        }
    }
}
```